# Discord.py bilingual help message

Tags: discord.py

Is it possible to create a bilingual help message using discord.py commands? So when `!help` is used, it shows the English help message and when another alias `!hilfe` is used, it shows the German one (for example)?

A simple solution would be to just implement the command separatly. But I am wondering whether there is an inbuilt solution.

Comment: Well, you need to create the messages and methods yourself. But you can check the clients locale and reply with the correct language that way. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ClientUser.locale

Comment: If you are using slash commands, you can check the user's locale with interaction.locale (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.locale) and then you don't even need separate command names. If you want to do it with prefix commands instead, you can use aliases in the decorator to give it multiple command names and use "ctx.invoked_with" to determine which was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see how the bot will respond, you can later edit it to your specific messages, maybe adding embeds and so on.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(name='help', aliases=['hilfe']) 
# here you can specify what language you want, ex : 'aliases=['hilfe', 'ayuda']'
async def help_command(ctx):
    command_prefix = bot.command_prefix
    if ctx.message.content.startswith(command_prefix + 'help'):
        language = 'English'
    elif ctx.message.content.startswith(command_prefix + 'hilfe'):
        language = 'German'
#   elif content.startswith(command_prefix + 'ayuda'):
#       language = 'Spanish'
    else:
        return

    
    if language == 'English':
        response = 'This is the help command. You can add information here in English.'
    elif language == 'German':
        response = 'Das ist der Hilfsbefehl. Sie können hier Informationen auf Deutsch hinzufügen.'
#   elif language == 'Spanish':
#       response = 'Este es el comando de ayuda. Puedes agregar información aquí en español.'
    else:
        response = 'Unsupported language.'

    await ctx.send(response)


bot.run('your_token')
```